# How to change JPanel using KeyListener?

Tags: java, jpanel

I want to change the JPanel I am displaying when I press the space bar. I know there are some topics on switching Panels, but none of them seem to use Keys and the format of those programs seem to be vastly different.
Here is my code:

This is my driver which sets up my JFrame and creates the StartPanel:

```
public class Driver
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game");
  frame.setSize(750, 900);
  frame.setLocation(250, 0);
  frame.setLayout(null);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  frame.setContentPane(new StartPanel());
  frame.setVisible(true);

 }
}
```

The firt panel I want to display:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;



public class StartPanel extends JPanel
{
  public StartPanel(){
     setOpaque(true);
     setBackground(Color.CYAN);
     setFocusable(true);
     addKeyListener(new Key());
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
     super.paintComponent(g);
     ImageIcon title = new ImageIcon("FreefallTitle.png");
     g.drawImage(title.getImage(), 50, 25, 400,100, null);

}

public class Key extends KeyAdapter 
{
     public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
     {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        System.out.println(key);
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) 
        {
          //switch  to Panel here
        }                         
     }  
  }
}
```

Comment: 1. Use [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), not a KeyListener, and 2. Swap with a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Comment: Side recommendation: never read in a file from within a painting method as this will slow your gui's painting down unnecessarily making it seem poorly responsive. Read the image in once and then store it in a variable that you use within paintComponent.